# Using the value of a placeholder (for an input box) as a condition in JS

Tags: javascript, html

(This is all made with HTML and JS)
I made this program that takes a decimal number, converts it into binary and gives you the result. The input box that takes the decimal number has a placeholder 'Enter decimal number'. After I made the decimal to binary part functional, I started on making a reverse button that would first change the placeholder to 'Enter binary number'. These are the HTML and JS codes:

```js
function reverseButton() {
                if (document.getElementsByClassName('inputBox').placeholder === 'Enter decimal number') {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('inputBox').placeholder='Enter binary number';
                } else if (document.getElementsByClassName('inputBox').placeholder === 'Enter binary number') {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('inputBox').placeholder='Enter decimal number';
                }
            }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="inputBox" id="decimalNumber" placeholder="Enter decimal number" min="0" step="0.0001">
<button class="button hoverTurquoise reverse" onclick="reverseButton()">Reverse</button>
```

I tried to first set the place holder to nothing (empty '') and then adding the text but I get the same result.
If anyone knows what to do, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName Function return an array so you have to convert your code to this form

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('inputBox')[0].placeholder === 'Enter decimal number') {
```